# Purposes of public ports in Azure endpoints?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, endpoint, network-traffic

Azure endpoints have to be implemented on VMs to let external traffic reach a VM inside a virtual network.

Such endpoints have public and private ports, which can be the same apparently.

What is the exact purpose of the public port? Is there any other purpose than simply hiding the private port of an application (say 1433 for SQL server for example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Endpoint are an old concept (dying our, really), with ARM you dont have those, you just have a public IP you attach to the VM (and you cant even do port mapping with public IP, you need load balancer for that)
2. There is no other purpose, only hiding the private port (which doesnt really change much against a port scan)